# $domxpath->query - Table Contents

Tags: php, domdocument, domxpath

has about two days I received the recommendation to use DOM document instead of regex

I still do not know how to use the query correctly

in the link below is the session "TERRITÓRIO E AMBIENTE", I would like to get the contents of the 4 lines below this

https://cidades.ibge.gov.br/brasil/sp/sao-paulo/panorama

```
$html = file_get_contents( 'https://cidades.ibge.gov.br/brasil/sp/sao-paulo/panorama' );    
            $document = new DOMDocument();              
            $document->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
            $domxpath = new DOMXPath($document);
            $paragraphs = $domxpath->query('
                //th[*[
                        contains(text(), "TERRITÓRIO E AMBIENTE")
                      ]
                    ]
                /following-sibling::tr[
                        position() = 12 
                    ]'
            );
```

I put the amount of 12 `<tr>` because that is what appears in the source code, but I do not know if I'm doing this query right, this is appearing these errors for me

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag app invalid in Entity, line: 25 
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Misplaced DOCTYPE declaration in Entity, line: 25
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseStartTag: misplaced <html> tag in Entity, line: 25
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues in your code.

- The HTML you get from that website is invalid, so you need to ignore errors (this is generally not recommended but in this case I think it's OK).

```
@$document->loadHTML($html);
```

- The text you're looking for is in lowercase (it's showing in uppercase because of its style), so you need to either normalize it or put the text in lowercase
- Your approach (getting the 12th child) is too brittle. I inspected the code a little and it's hard make it less brittle but I think this comes close:

```
//th[contains(text(), "Território e Ambiente")]/parent::tr/following-sibling::tr[1]/td[3]
```

That gets a `th` element containing the text `Território e Ambiente`, then gets the parent `tr` tag, then goes to the next `tr` sibling, and finally gets the third `td` element (where the value is). Still *very* brittle but keep an eye on changes in the website, it's unlikely to change.

So now you need to repeat that XPath query 3 more times, changing the nth `tr` sibling (adding two, because there's an empty element in the middle of each). It ends up looking something like this:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
@$document->loadHTML($html);
$domxpath = new DOMXPath($document);
$paragraphs = $domxpath->query('//th[contains(text(), "Território e Ambiente")]/parent::tr/following-sibling::tr[1]/td[3]');
echo "First: ".preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $paragraphs[0]->nodeValue);
echo "<br>";
$paragraphs = $domxpath->query('//th[contains(text(), "Território e Ambiente")]/parent::tr/following-sibling::tr[3]/td[3]');
echo "Second: ".preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $paragraphs[0]->nodeValue);
echo "<br>";
$paragraphs = $domxpath->query('//th[contains(text(), "Território e Ambiente")]/parent::tr/following-sibling::tr[5]/td[3]');
echo "Third: ".preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $paragraphs[0]->nodeValue);
echo "<br>";
$paragraphs = $domxpath->query('//th[contains(text(), "Território e Ambiente")]/parent::tr/following-sibling::tr[7]/td[3]');
echo "Fourth: ".preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $paragraphs[0]->nodeValue);
```

> First:  1.521,110 km²
>   Second:  92,6 %
>   Third:  74,8 %
>   Fourth:  50,3 %

Note the use of `preg_replace()` to get rid of the abundant whitespace.

And using a little more XPath magic we can get it to work with only one query:

```
//th[contains(text(), "Território e Ambiente")]/parent::tr/following-sibling::tr[position() mod 2 = 1]/td[3]
```

Works the same as the others, but instead of getting a specific `tr` sibling element, gets every other one.

```
$paragraphs = $domxpath->query('//th[contains(text(), "Território e Ambiente")]/parent::tr/following-sibling::tr[position() mod 2 = 1]/td[3]');
foreach ($paragraphs as $i => $p) {
    echo ($i + 1)." value: ".preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $p->nodeValue);
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Again it worked perfectly, thank you very much @ishegg